# Web2py Why did ajax call keep sending empty data after refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax, web2py

I'm checking for empty field in the form,only be send when all fields are filled

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $normalClass=$(".normalClass"); //input fields class
var $username=$("#username");
var $password=$("#password");
var $email=$("#email");
var emptyField=1;  //keeping track of empty fields in the form


$("#submit").click(function (){
var emptyField=0;
$normalClass.each(function () {
    if($(this).val()===""){
        emptyField++;
        $("#formSU").submit(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
        $(this).after("<p class='errorClass2'>This field is required.</p>");
    }
});
if(emptyField==0) {
    alert("all filled");
    $.ajax({
        url: "dbQuery", 
        data: {
            username: $username.val(),
            password: $password.val(),
            email:    $email.val()
        },
        success: function () { alert("success");                 
        },
        type: 'POST'
    }); //end ajax
}
```

At first,I thought that because I didn't declare emptyField's value before the submit event,the ajax will keep sending empty data.But after giving it a non 0 the form still sent after refreshing.I even put ajax call inside the submit event and only when there is no empty field.
What did I do wrong and how can I make the code easier to read?
Edit:adding the html,controller and the framework:

```
<div class="ftable">
<form method="post" id="formSU">
<input type="text" class="normalClass" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
<input type="password" class="normalClass" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
<label for="checkBox">Show password</label></br>
<input type="email" class="normalClass" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
<input data-w2p_disable_with="Submit" type="submit" value = "Submit" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def signup():
db.user.insert(username=request.vars.username,
password=request.vars.password,email = request.vars.email)
return dict()
```

Comment: Note, your controller will insert a record in `db.user` even when the form page is first loaded (before submitting the form) -- in that case, all the field values will be `None`. Also, your Ajax URL is a relative URL, so it actually points to the URL of the current page, with "dbQuery" appended (e.g., if the current page URL is /default/signup, the Ajax request will go to /default/signup/dbQuery). In that case, "dbQuery" will be the value of `request.args[0]`, not the name of a controller function. Also, your form includes no CSRF protection.

Comment: If you want to submit the form via Ajax, a better approach would be to put the form inside an [Ajax component](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins#Components--LOAD-and-Ajax). You should also use `SQLFORM` to handle the form processing and database insert (you can still use custom HTML in the view if desired). If you need help with these things, ask on the Google Group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snipped , if u hv any query plz comment. i think `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: 'POST'`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    // when form submit
     $("#formSU").submit(function (){

     var $normalClass=$(".normalClass"); //input fields class
     var $username=$("#username");
     var $password=$("#password");
     var $email=$("#email");

     var errors = []    

      if($username.val() == "")
      {
        errors.push({ ele : $username,
                     msg : "<p class='errorClass2'>This field is required.</p>"           
                    });
        //return false; // prevents form submitting
      }
     if($password.val() == "")
      {
        errors.push({ ele : $password,
                     msg : "<p class='errorClass2'>This field is required.</p>"           
                    });
        //return false; // prevents form submitting
      }
     if($email.val() == "")
      {
        errors.push({ ele : $email,
                     msg : "<p class='errorClass2'>This field is required.</p>"           
                    });
        ///return false; // prevents form submitting
      }

  if(errors.length)
  {
     for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++)
     {
       var o = errors[i];
        o.ele.after(o.msg);
     }

    return false;
  }



         // if reaches here means all filled
            $.ajax({
                url: "dbQuery", 
                data: {
                    username: $username.val(),
                    password: $password.val(),
                    email:    $email.val()
                },
                success: function () { alert("success");                 
                },
                method: 'POST'
            }); //end ajax
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but the error text is only showed one at a time,not after all blank fields and the submitting empty data problem is still there.

Comment: the error codes worked like a charm but i still have that problem.I'm sorry but if possible could you check your codes on a ide,because this could be my framework acting up and i'm wasting your time.
Edit:I added an alert right before the ajax and it didn't show up so the ajax call should not run